# How do familiars, animal companions, cohorts, followers, and the like fit into the wealth by level progression?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, animal-companions, wealth, followers-and-hirelings

Though I am not advocating a strict adherence to the wealth by level progression, if that progression is used, how would "extra crew members" of PCs fit on the chart?  The leadership feat text does indicate that the "cohort does not count as a party member when determining the party's XP".  Does this also apply to wealth?  Does a higher level PC with a cohort and followers via the leadership feat factor the equipment of the cohort and all of the followers into the wealth of the PC?  Or does each individual entity track wealth separately?  How does a DM figure out, if the cohort / follower(s) is brought on an adventure, what amount of treasure to reward the party with?  And to a lesser extent, how does this apply to familiars and animal companions who may support certain item slots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XP:
“The Cohort does not count as a party member when determining the **PARTY**'s XP”

To determine XP: “Divide the cohort’s level by the level of the PC with whom (s)he is associated with. Multiply this result by the total XP awarded to the PC & add that number of xp to the cohort’s total.

IF a cohort gains enough XP to bring it to a level one lower than the associated PC’s Character level, the cohort does NOT gain the new level-it’s new XP total is 1 less than the amount needed to level up. (Cohorts must be at least 2 levels lower than the PC)

Wealth: (**Edited** with reference)
“The cohort should be equipped with gear appropriate for its’ level.”  This is for "starting wealth"  Once they adventure with the party they are entitled to **some** treasure.

**DMG** *pg 105*:
"Although the PCs can work out other deals, their cohorts usually get only a half share of any treasure the party gains."

"sometimes a cohort seeks no pay, only the opportunity to serve alongside the PCs.  Such cohorts require only living costs.  However, they are not common."

Comment: Find anything else regarding cohorts expecting wealth from the PC / party?

Comment: I have updated the wealth portion on how to deal with treasure

Comment: @Ben-Jamin aha! Upvoted, and updated my own answer to direct people to yours for more correct info.

Answer (score 11):

### Cohort gets half a share of treasure

See @Ben-Jamin’s answer.

Personally, I feel that Leadership is already an incredibly powerful feat. Making the Leader pay for that opportunity to double their action economy seems entirely justifiable to me. Making the feat double your action economy **and** add extra wealth seems even worse than it is otherwise.

### Familiars, Animal Companions, Psicrystals, et al. do not get wealth

These are still NPCs, but were they not attached to another character they most likely would not have treasure, and in a few of these cases they literally cannot exist as separate characters. Any gear they wind up wearing should be paid for by the master, just as a knight would pay for his horse’s barding.

Comment: I really should find a citation for the Cohort bit, but I've seen this discussed without finding a resolution before so for now I'm assuming there is none. I personally ban Leadership in every game I run, and play with DMs who do the same or else heavily tweak it to make it more reasonable.

Comment: Making matters worse, suppose a character doesn't take the Leadership feat until 18th level.  Suddenly, a potentially 16th level cohort joins the party "equipped with gear appropriate for its level" (feat description).  What constitutes "appropriate" is the crux of this question, but any way you cut it, that is a significant amount of wealth that just waltzed into the party without a new PC joining the game.

Comment: Ummmmm...... my crossbow trigger finger is a bit slower than you expect? :)  Your answer is thus upvoted.

Comment: I dont have my books on me atm, but I thiought there was a RAW definition that said the cohort expected a fair share of the loot..meaning basically it comes out of the party's share?  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Ben-Jamin If so, I've missed it and yes, it sounds like you'd be correct. Post the answer if you can find the cite, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Fun fact: your cohort can have leadership, too.

Comment: @Mikalichov There's actually a trick where your Psicrystal can have a Psicrystal that is a higher level than it... which can have a Psicrystal higher level than that that, and so on. *Complete Psionics* was not a well-written or well-edited book.

Comment: @KRyan I updated the wealth chart as promised (even if it was a bit late)

Comment: @MattHamsmith, I know this is old, but rereading this I wanted to point out that a lvl 16 NPC has only 77K GP, equivalent to about an 11.5 PC. So the gear will not be anything overly bad but ur point still remains valid.